# Safe chaining in scalaz Disjunction

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I'm trying to wrap my head around scalaz disjunctions (\/) but it does not click yet. Consider the following:

```
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> def danger(i: Int): Int = throw new Exception("boom")
danger: (i: Int)Int

scala> \/-(1).map(danger)
java.lang.Exception: boom
  at .danger(<console>:10)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:12)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:12)
  at scalaz.$bslash$div.map(Either.scala:111)
  ... 43 elided
```

My naive expectation was that since I invoke `danger` inside `\/.map` the last statement should have returned `-\/(Exception("boom"))`, not blowing up.

I can fix it with

```
scala> \/-(1).flatMap(i => \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal(danger(i)))
res4: scalaz.\/[Throwable,Int] = -\/(java.lang.Exception: boom)
```

but this gets horribly verbose and out of control. Is there a simpler way for safely chaining transformations with disjunctions?

Comment: Now, that I read it again, I think you already have better abstraction `fromTryCatchNonFatal`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, `danger` should return you `\/[A, B]`. if you cannot modify the return type of `danger`, create a version dangerousFn. This will enable you to flatMap in functional way.
Edit: After re-reading OP's solution, I am using `fromTryCatchNonFatal` function

---

```
import scalaz._

def danger(i: Int): Int = throw new Exception("boom")
val dangerousFn = (danger _).andThen(\/.fromTryCatchNonFatal)

for {
  num <- \/-(1)
  value <- dangerousFn(num)
} yield {
  "This will never be reached"
}
```

*Output:*

```
import scalaz._

danger: danger[](val i: Int) => Int

res0: scalaz.\/[Throwable,String] = -\/(java.lang.Exception: boom)
```

Comment: Right, I could wrap `danger` and have a for-comprehension, but having a separate function for the sake of converting to `\/` for every piece of code seems suboptimal.